# Windows getting please wait and booting slow

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, windows-10

**Hello**
I have a dualboot system on ASUS X55C and have installed Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10. I have installed Ubuntu in dual boot about a month ago. After installing it successfully I can see please wait before logging in Windows and it also requires more time to boot up and wake from sleep. I am sure that its cause is dualboot because I have done reinstalling Windows. Thankyou.

Comment: Do you have "fast boot" enabled? If so, that will contribute to the problem as Windows will detect something amiss and do a disk check at boot time. This is particularly true if you have configured your Ubuntu installation to read/write to the Windows partition while "fast boot" is enabled.

Comment: No fast boot is disabled from earlier when Ubuntu was not installed and now after reinstalling Windows I disabled it again.@Matigo